# Query from two tables having same id field

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have 2 tables.

Table A - 2 columns(id, class A) and table B - 2 columns (id, class B)

I have find out whether class A and class B are same in the following two tables. If it changes then i have to display the changed records as id, Class A, class B format

But am unable to get the correct result when the same id have 2 or more classes. Tried a lot but could not get the req output.

Table A:

```
id           class A    
1              10             
1              20             
3              50             
4              60
```

Table B:

```
id           class B    
1              20             
1              30             
3              50             
4              60
```

Require Out put:

```
id       Class A      Class B
1          10           30
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it :

```
SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.CLASSA NOT IN (SELECT CLASSA FROM A, B
WHERE CLASSA = CLASSB) AND CLASSB NOT IN (SELECT CLASSA FROM A, B
WHERE CLASSA = CLASSB)
```

sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9a42/10

Comment: This work but make you have a two indexes like this PRIMARY KEY(CLASSA, ID) and PRIMARY KEY(CLASSB, ID) or this query will run 6 full table scans and this is not good..

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do:

```
  Select A.id,A.classA,B.classB from A inner join B
  on A.id=B.id
  where A.classA!=B.classB
```